# What if I hit a pedestrian and killed him? what are the steps in both cases?

Tags: traffic

I'm an engineering student taking a course called traffic safety. A project in the course gives a problem to solve which is:

> A cousin of yours have accidentally hit a pedestrian while getting out of the parking lot. The pedestrian, a man in his 70s, was taken to the hospital with serious injuries (internal bleeding and fractured rib) with the help of the Red Cross.
>
> You came to the hospital and knew that the injured person is dead.
>
> Kindly list the steps that your cousin should follow from the moment he hit the pedestrian to the
> moment of death. You should mention who should he called, who should come to the hospital, who should write the accident report and what should the report include and what will happen to your cousin if:
>
> - Case A: The family of the victim have decided to prosecute.
> - Case B: The family of the victim did not decide to prosecute.

#### What i did so far is:

I stated that my cousin should first move his car away to prevent further collisions, then instantly call the ambulance and the police. He should also ask for any witness to remain in the scene. When police arrives, the officer collects the information such as ID, road condition, age, gender, driving experience, phone number, location, time... Then he should call insurance company and report the accident to them. Finally, call the attorney.

**My question is how can i elaborate further in discussing this, my instructor requires it to be 3-4 pages. I'm barely being able to write one page. Any idea on how can I elaborate more on this? what should i also mention, should I search for traffic laws in my country and mention them?**

Not asking to solve my entire homework, just some hints or tips maybe?

Comment: "should i search for traffic laws in my country and mention them?"  Er, yes.  Yes, you should.

Comment: you haven't said anything about who is to write the accident report or what it will contain.

Comment: As an engineer, I'm attempting to understand why this kind of hypothetical is part of an engineering course. The scenario described above seems more appropriate as part of either a driver's education class or a class on law. Alternately, is your class focused upon legal ramifications and ethics associated with poor engineering designs? Or is the course focused on roadway design issues that could contribute to frequent accidents (i.e. poor sight distances) and subsequent lawsuits? Additionally, your country may be helpful to providing context here.

Comment: Where is this happening

Comment: Dont move the car until you are absolutely certain its both necessary and not detrimental to the victim - send other people up and down the road to safely slow traffic where possible, use cones etc if available.  It does not matter if your vehicle is blocking the thoroughfare if moving it causes further injury.

Comment: How would the family's interest in prosecuting have anything to do with the orderly making the scene safe and documenting what happened as a traffic professional? And wouldn't that information not be available to quite a while after the accident?

Answer (score 1):

Your question answers the first few matters.

> who should come to the hospital,

Not necessarily your cousin. It could be viewed as witness tampering.

> who should write the accident report

The police.

> and what should the report include

A diagram of the accident with location and speed details as exact as possible (e.g. detail skid marks or lack thereof), description of intersection, ID details for each party and the vehicle, insurance information for driver, drug/alcohol assessment for driver and pedestrian, mental state assessment for driver and pedestrian, description of the car, statements from the parties and all witnesses (and mention of all surveillance cameras in the area with notice to owner of them to preserve the material), time, date, place, amount of traffic, weather, traffic conditions, any exceptional facts, and the cop's name. Photos would also be good. A sample form is below:

[image]

> and what will happen to your cousin if:

He's likely to be sued for wrongful death by the victim's next of kin if they don't prosecute, and to be prosecuted for careless driving and several other traffic offenses as the incident warrants, and for vehicular homicide/negligent homicide.

There are a lengthy civil procedure process in the lawsuit case and a lengthy criminal process in the prosecution case. Also, while the lawsuit implies that the victim's next of kin must decide to prosecute or not, the decision is actually up to the DA who can disregard their wishes if he or she wants to do so. In a prosecution, the DA and law enforcement handle most of the investigation. In a civil lawsuit this is handled by counsel hired by the insurance company and a lawyer for the family in the wrongful death action usually on a contingent basis.

**Footnote**

Is the instructor's native language not English?